# TypeORM with React Native

Tags: react-native, sqlite, typeorm

I created a new dummy app with `react-native init test`, and then followed the instructions to add typeorm. In my App.js I included `import {getManager} from 'typeorm'`, and then ran `react-native run-ios`.

I see the following error in metro-bundler:

```
Error: Unable to resolve module path from /Users/amit/Code/test/node_modules/typeorm/platform/PlatformTools.js: Module path does not exist in the Haste module map
```

Here's a sample repository to show the problem: [enter link description here](https://github.com/heroic/react-native-test)

Not sure if I missed something in the setup! Any help is really welcome!

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately import from 'typeorm' module does not work because react-native projects does not use node platform excatly. Imports from 'typeorm/browser' will work. Here is a sample project.: https://github.com/typeorm/react-native-example

Make sure you create a connection object that does not use any references to project file system. Avoid using something like:

```
import { CountSession } from '../biopro-mobile-database/entities/count_session';

   const connection = await createConnection({
            name: 'liteDb_3',
            type: 'react-native',
            database: 'biopro_mobile.sqlite',
            location: 'default',
            synchronize: false,
            logging: true,
            entities: ["../biopro-mobile-database/entities/**/*.ts"],
          })
```

Avoid **entities: ["../biopro-mobile-database/entities/**/*.ts"],**
Instead use something like:

```
import { EquipmentCounted } from '../biopro-mobile-database/entities/equipment_counted';
import { CountSession } from '../biopro-mobile-database/entities/count_session';

   const connection = await createConnection({
            name: 'liteDb_3',
            type: 'react-native',
            database: 'biopro_mobile.sqlite',
            location: 'default',
            synchronize: false,
            logging: true,
            entities: [
              CountSession,
              EquipmentCounted,
            ],
          })
```

Comment: Is anyone using TypeORM in a react native app in production?  I would love to find an ORM replacement for Realm.  I cannot get https://github.com/typeorm/react-native-example to run on either Android or iOS.  
https://github.com/typeorm/react-native-example/issues/4
https://github.com/typeorm/react-native-example/issues/2